# How to style a group of (nested) elements using one style reference

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'd like to know whether there's a **simple** (I believe there's a complex workaround for everything) way to style a group of potentially nested elements while referencing just one style on the parent element level in XAML/WPF.

In HTML/CSS it is possible to do:

```
<div class="levels"><!--1st level; only reference to the style-->
  <div><!--2nd level-->
    <div></div><!--3rd level-->
  </div>
  <div></div><!--2nd level-->
</div>
```

and then style it by:

```
.levels {
  width: 400px; height: 400px;
  background-color:red;}

.levels div {
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
  background-color:green;}

.levels div div {
  width: 50px; height: 50px;
  background-color:yellow;}
```

This makes it possible to reference the style "levels" only once on the parent element and then worry about the referencing no more, so when a new element is added later under the parent element (either in xaml or dynamically in code) you don't need keep in mind to also add "class=levelx" to the new element.

Is the same possible in XAML/WPF? The BasedOn property doesn't seem to be what I want as: a) I'm not looking for a property inheritance, b) unless the new style has a defined x:Key it is applied to all elements of given TargetType and if it does, then once again you need to reference it on the given element (`Style="{static resource levelx}"`). `<Setter Property="Grid.Grid.Background" Value"Red">` unfortunately doesn't work.

What is then the proper way to style such a group of elements? Referencing a specific style on each nested element seems to me unnecessarily messy.

Here's a concrete example of an element structure, but I consider this to be a general question for many different situations:

```
<Grid Style="{StaticResource Levels}"><!--1st level-->
    <Grid><!--2nd level-->
        <Grid></Grid><!--3rd level-->
        <Image Source="/Resources/xxx.png"/><!--3rd level-->
    </Grid>
    <Grid><!--2nd level-->
        <Grid></Grid><!--3rd level-->
        <Image Source="/Resources/yyy.png" x:Name="yyy"/><!--3rd level-->
    </Grid>
    <Grid><!--2nd level-->
        <Image Source="/Resources/zzz.png"/><!--3rd level-->
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

This is probably a duplicate, but I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: What sort of properties do you aim to share among the nested elements?
something like width, height, margin and such?
It may be just me but your XAML example doesn't exactly show the duplication in properties you wish to avoid.
Could you please elaborate on the things you wish to narrow down?

Comment: @MichaelThePotato Yes, such properties exactly. For example, I'd like the parent grid to have red background, while ANY nested grid on the 2nd level to have green background and ANY grid on 3rd level to have yellow background or ANY image on 3rd level (meaning only under 2nd-lvl grid) to be of certain height/width and so on without having to specify a reference to style for each of these elements. Just like the CSS in the example.

Comment: What's your exact definition of "level" exactly?
I assume the parent grid is the first level, and do you mean all the direct children grids as the second level?
Or do you mean that the one that owns the XXX image is the second level, the one that owns the YYY is the third and so on?

Comment: @MichaelThePotato I've edited the example in my post. The wrapper grid is the 1st lvl, grids containing images are 2nd and all elements contained by 2nd lvl grids are 3rd level (added 3rd level grids now).

Comment: Just saw your edit. thanks for the clarification, but I regret to inform you that to the best of my knowledge, relative style application as you wish it to be in a simple manner, doesn't exist in XAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want might not be exactly possible. Particularly for n levels. Something like this would give you desired behavior over two levels.

CONTENT

```
    <Grid Style="{StaticResource Levels}">
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="20 20 0 0" Height="60">
            <Grid Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center"></Grid>
                <Label></Label>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="20 100 0 0" Height="60">
            <Grid Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center"></Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="20 180 0 0" Height="60">
            <Grid Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center"></Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

STYLE DEFINITION

```
  <Style x:Key="Levels" TargetType="Grid">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="400"></Setter>
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Grid">
                <Setter Property="Grid.Background" Value="Purple"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"></Setter>
                <Style.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="Grid">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"></Setter>
                        <Style.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="Grid">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Tomato"></Setter>
                            </Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Label">
                                <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
                                <Setter Property="Width" Value="20"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Azure"/>
                            </Style>
                        </Style.Resources>
                    </Style>
                </Style.Resources>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
```

Comment: There's no pm on SO, so: I wasn't going to accept your answer as it didn't seem to add anything to my current knowledge and didn't seem to provide actual solution I was looking for, but then the behavior of <Style.Resources> surprised me and thanks to you, I think I was able to find a solution (seems like hack, but it works). I don't want to rob you of the correct answer so if you'd be willing to alter your answer according to this: https://justpaste.it/x2dy, I'll gladly accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: Great ;) This seems to do exactly what I was looking for over as many levels as needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean something like this.

```
<Grid Margin="20">
  <Grid.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="Grid">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"></Setter>
  </Style>
  </Grid.Resources>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
  <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
  <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Margin="20" Height="20" Grid.Row="0">
    </Grid>
    <Grid Margin="20" Height="20" Grid.Row="1" Background="Yellow">
    </Grid>
    <Grid Margin="20" Height="20" Grid.Row="2">
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I might be wrong, but I don't think this is what I'm looking for, because: a) I'd like to have a reference to one style on the parent element; and more importantly b) would this somehow allow me to also style 3rd/4th levels of various elements (grid, image, button...)?

Comment: I am not sure what u mean exactly by reference to style.
You can have multiple resources at that level one for each of the element types. 
You can also try to have keys to some of the reference x:Key to one of the elements and refer it later.

Comment: By "referencing a style" I mean pointing to it for example by: `Style="{Static resource MyStyle}"` - but that's not too important since your solution is just an inline equivalent of the referenced style. The real problem here is that by defining TargetType="grid" you're, I believe, setting the properties to ALL the grids within the grid and the grid itself, but what I want is to be able to set different styles for grid on each of the levels. Just as the CSS does. How would you set a different height/width to all grids on the 3rd/4th level?